# using pod 'GoogleMaps' in iOS project getting error

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

using pod 'GoogleMaps' in iOS project getting "Unexpected failure" error other pods working fine

tried using in Swift UIKit as well as in SwiftUI project still getting same error in both

used pod

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'GoogleMap' do
pod 'GoogleMaps', '8.3.1'
end`

Comment: Is this the guide you followed? https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMaps